# How come orbit image slider plugin isn't working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm setting up orbit according to this [guide](http://zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider) and for some reason it is not working at all. I'm sure its something incredibly simple being that there are only like 2 steps to follow, but I'm really not seeing it and could use a second set of eyes. Let me know if you see what the issue is, thanks!

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.orbit.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/orbit.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).load(function() {
     $('#featured').orbit();
 });
</script>
<div id="featured"> 
 <img src="1.jpg" alt="Overflow: Hidden No More" />
 <img src="2.jpg"  alt="HTML Captions" />
 <img src="3.jpg" alt="and more features" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your paths to jQuery and orbit JS files are correct and loading.

Try using `$(document).ready();`

```
    <div id="featured"> 
     <img src="1.jpg" alt="Overflow: Hidden No More" />
     <img src="2.jpg"  alt="HTML Captions" />
     <img src="3.jpg" alt="and more features" />
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#featured').orbit();
     });
    </script>
```